# Is EncryptedSharedPreference safety?

Tags: android, xml, encryption, sharedpreferences

Recently I tried [encrypted shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data#edit-shared-preferences). But I can't understand what a key and value exist in my preference.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="ARLnAHud5NbRh7oPQc1fRGJRt9gBIh/+TZTg0aRVbweicg7Gy64OC9oB1dwqIDQ1tOiPgbR3FnZ2Snrx6+Zyv9zZjSVOb+1nPJsAJhwkHn1sSQ==">ATVwNMDZykhefHmBCxVhk+hpIIIBxpuqgdZLFk76tba2U7JpaKoErwVfCeJMforkFk69eSZ/OldGQT6C</string>
    <string name="__androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_key_keyset__">12a90122e4ed117563cb2ff2cf8d53026540e8faaaabb8c8ee220c788dfda99e6eee0fecc602522b296ba7d47d411ad05ac94768674904f588ff937fe5a978ca3e975c56abfa0ffef1c00e93d4f8856e15bc22acc94ad41ec1dd040f6907dfb679012b476c53da1b92b2599ce1d5a10533bab99dcb08fb164bb481539679fef22edb809c8b958f12ed2bd7e99543538009bec8d82e4ec2c367be64d4aacb3f306d07db54e353494eff550b171a4408fb809c9701123c0a30747970652e676f6f676c65617069732e636f6d2f676f6f676c652e63727970746f2e74696e6b2e4165735369764b6579100118fb809c97012001</string>
    <string name="__androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_value_keyset__">1288011f4e27b26101312afa85ed9de4ecf6cc4478d7f776758c07ef034046c18598d6fd0956165a34b6227301b6d10d652ce9f48ef7757878c10ebc326ba853830be152b9bff188bb905adad67b70a5a076750a80d286c6a619550ce70a7b1f4b81b1782ce103be500d350ba3d148caef2ebb82315189a3f03c9ffae7fbd0fc69cff32bc0e435f96693691a4408c0e9c0ab03123c0a30747970652e676f6f676c65617069732e636f6d2f676f6f676c652e63727970746f2e74696e6b2e41657347636d4b6579100118c0e9c0ab032001</string>
</map>
```

Seems that data need for authontification between pref.xml and [Android keystore system](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore). But 
i guess these values are sensetive, why they need here?

Comment: This title is strange. Shouldn't it be "Is EncryptedSharedPreference safe?" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `EncryptedSharedPreferences` is to encrypt your `SharedPreferences`. so you don't have to handle your data directly from the XML file and about those tow keys they mentioned that [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data#key-management).

> The Security library uses a 2-part system for key management:
>
> > A keyset that contains one or more keys to encrypt a file or shared preferences data. 
> >      
> > The keyset itself is stored in SharedPreferences.
> >     A master key that encrypts all keysets. This key is stored using the Android keystore system.